# SQL : 3 table joins with NULL values

Tags: sql, mysql

Ahh...been banging my head against this because I cant seem to figure it out.

My tables:

```
$ select * from my_family_members;
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------+
| member_id | house_id  | member_name                 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------+
|  2        |         2 | Ash                         |
|  5        |         5 | Mel                         |
|  8        |         2 | NULL                        |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------+

$ select * from my_houses;
+------------------------------------------+
| house_id | code     | house_name         |
+------------------------------------------+
|  2       | house1   | My Blue house      |
|  5       | house2   | My Red house       |
|  8       | house3   | My Green house     |
|  9       | house4   | My Pink House      |
+------------------------------------------+


$ select * from my_pets;
+-----------+--------------+----------------+
|house_id   | config_key   | config_value   |
+-----------+--------------+----------------+
| 2         | cat          | Tom            |
| 2         | cat          | Jerry          |
| 5         | dog          | Buster         |
| 8         | cat          | Bubbles        |        
+-----------+--------------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to do a query that will get me house_id, member_id and config_value of their cats including NULL values. ie:

```
+---------------+------------------------------+
| house_name    | member_name  |  cats         |
+---------------+------------------------------+
| My Blue House | Ash          |  Jerry        |
| My Blue House | Ash          |  Tom          |
| My Red House  | Mel          |  NULL         |
| My Green House| NULL         |  Bubbles      |
| My Pink House | NULL         |  NULL         |
+---------------+------------------------------+
```

I tried a query like:

```
select mh.house_name, mfm.member_name, config_value as cats
from my_pets mp
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_houses mh
ON mp.house_id=mh.house_id 
JOIN my_family_members mfm
ON mfm.house_id=mh.house_id
where config_key = 'cat' order by house_name;
```

But I can only get:

```
+---------------+------------------------------+
| house_name    | member_name  |  cats         |
+---------------+------------------------------+
| My Blue House | Ash          |  Jerry        |
| My Blue House | Ash          |  Tom          |
+---------------+------------------------------+
```

What do I need to change to get the result I want?

EDIT: The logic is that there is always a house, but the house can have a  cat without actually having anyone living in it so member_name is NULL and cat is not NULL (poor cat..), there can also be a house with a member with no cat (cat is NULL, but member is not NULL), and lastly there can also be a house with no one in it and no cats (cat is NULL, member_name is NULL, although there might be a dog but I only want to see if there is a cat or people in the house).

Further edit: I have a critical mistake here while translating my actual problem, onto a hypothetical problem here on stackoverflow. I realized in my_pets table it actually has house_id column, NOT member_id column. Apologies for the confusion......I've corrected my data set above.

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is `where config_key = 'cat'`.  When you have nulls or the outer join extends missing records to nulls, the config_key will be null and the where clause will exclude them.  You could replace config_key with `Coalesce(config_key,'cat')` but even that might not be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thats a fair question, but there is a requirement in my query to show a NULL result for houses that dont have a cat.

Comment: Regarding the edit you made to your question, your data model does not allow for a house with a cat but no people - the only link between house and pet is via a person

Comment: You are absolutely right @NickW I have a mistake in my example dataset! Its actually house_id column in the my_cats table (rather than member_id).  I've corrected this. So sorry  for the confusion....although that still didn't help my problem :( but hopefully it gives better understanding for you guys to actually help point me in the right direction!

Comment: So do you want to show a row for every possible combination of house, person and cat (including nulls for people and cats) - so if a house had 2 people and 2 cats you would have 4 records for that house?

Comment: Yep, thats exactly right!

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be approaching the problem from the wrong direction. You want all houses so start with that table (my_houses). You then want people who live in each house - without excluding houses with no people - so left join people (my_family_members) to houses. You then want any pets that exist - without excluding houses/people - so left join pets (my_pets) to people.

So something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM my_houses h
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_family_members fm ON h.house_id = fm.house_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_pets p ON fm.member_id = p.member_id
```

**SECOND ANSWER**

I assume leaving the name as null for member 8 was a typo, as a person has to have a name?
This hopefully gives you what you want. If it doesn't then you may want to consider closing this question and taking some time to think through what you are trying to achieve and then create a new question that accurately depicts the table structures, all the possible scenarios and the result you want

```
WITH members AS (
    SELECT H.HOUSE_ID, M.MEMBER_ID, M.MEMBER_NAME
    FROM my_houses H
    LEFT OUTER JOIN my_family_members M ON H.HOUSE_ID = M.HOUSE_ID
),
PETS AS (
    SELECT H.HOUSE_ID, P.CONFIG_VALUE
    FROM my_houses H
    LEFT OUTER JOIN my_pets P ON H.HOUSE_ID = P.HOUSE_ID AND P.CONFIG_KEY = 'cat'
),
members_pets AS(
    SELECT M.HOUSE_ID, M.MEMBER_ID, M.MEMBER_NAME, P.CONFIG_VALUE
    FROM members M
    FULL OUTER JOIN pets P ON M.HOUSE_ID = P.HOUSE_ID
)
SELECT H.HOUSE_ID, H.HOUSE_NAME
,MP.MEMBER_NAME, MP.CONFIG_VALUE
FROM my_houses H
LEFT OUTER JOIN members_pets MP ON H.HOUSE_ID = MP.HOUSE_ID
;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is close but unfortunately although its now showing My_Red_House as having Mel as a member_name, it shows Buster in the cats column although Buster is a dog. I want this column for Mel to be NULL :(

Comment: Yes, you would need to adjust the join conditions to match your actual requirements. This was only meant to get you started on the right track

Comment: Gotcha. However the thing I'm struggling with right now is actually adjusting that join condition. I'm not knowledgeable enough to know how to adjust the condition so it wont filter out Mel completely....